# python executable created with pyinstaller does not work in windows virtual machine

Tags: python, windows, virtual-machine, pyinstaller

Greetings to the community.

I am experiencing a very strange behavior from an executable i created with pyinstaller 4.3.

The executable is a windows service that works as intended in a windows physical machine (windows 10).

But when the same executable is run through a windows virtual machine it crashes with no message.

i use service.exe install. normally you get a message saying that the service is installed.
In the virtual machine there is no message. There is also a logger implemented in my code but it shows nothing.

The strange thing is that when i run the source code of the service inside a command line and not as an executable it also runs fine in the VM.

So the problem is connected with pyinstaller i think

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the exe in the VM not as a service, from a commandline so you can see any error messages?

Comment: yes i did try that. i edited the question. thanks

Comment: FYI Using apache daemon procrun you can redirect stdout and stderr to files.